# Text replacement - speed up this Cursor?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, cursor

I am using SQL Server. I have a table that has injections into another piece of text.

Where `iBegin` is the location of the injection inserted in the text
and `iEnd` another insert for the injection

So if a text says

```
Hello how are you today
```

and injection iBegin = 3 and iEnd = 7 and xStatus is CopyRights, then will add a copyright symbol at these locations.

```
Hel©lo h©ow are you today
```

Here is the datasource

```
ID   iRepID  xStatus     iBegin   iEnd
--------------------------------------
1    1001    Registered   4        6   
2    1001    CopyRights   9       15
3    1001    Hat         18       22
4    2002    CopyRights   2        7   
5    2002    Registered   4       11
6    2002    Dollar      15       18
```

And my text of this Reps that has the main text:

```
This is a test report, will be used for testing
```

So the final result will be like this

```
This® i®s a© test ©rep^ort,^ will be used for testing
```

Another example using RepID 2002:

```
Hi There, Hope you had a good day. Pray for Gaza.
```

This will become

```
Hi© T®her©e, H®ope $you$ had a good day. Pray for Gaza.
```

Here is the code I wrote

```
DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT iRepID, xStatus, iBegin, iEnd
    WHERE iRepID = 1001

OPEN db_cursor  
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @iRepID, @xStatus, @iBegin, @iEnd

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN     
    SET @Mark = CASE @xStatus 
                    WHEN 'Registered' THEN '®' 
                    WHEN 'CopyRights' THEN '©' 
                    WHEN 'Hat' THEN '^' 
                END

    SET @RepSub = @Mark + ISNULL(SUBSTRING(@RepText, @iBegin, @iEnd-@iBegin + 1), '') + @Mark
    
    SET @RepText = ISNULL(LEFT(@RepText, @iBegin - 1), '') + @RepSub + ISNULL(SUBSTRING(@RepText, @IEnd+1, @RepLen), '')

    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @iRepID, @xStatus, @iBegin, @iEnd 
END 

CLOSE db_cursor  
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

Is there a much faster script? Because this script will go in a function for a 1 million row table.

Comment: You seem to be missing a `FROM TableName` in your cursor definition. Anyway is the un-named table, could 2 different rows ever overlap each other? i.e. could `iEnd` of one row be higher than `iBegin` of the next?

Comment: Personally when I have needed to do anything requiring lots of string manipulation I use a CLR function.

Comment: Seems there's a bug in your code, cause you don't get two symbols. If this table is fixed, you could probably generate a dynamic sql containing some clever function calls that did everything in one. This won't work with function though.  Also, check out the `STUFF` function, i haven't bothered trying to dechiffer your code, but it seems like it could come in handy. Also, generally for these tasks, one wants to iterate backwards, to avoid indexes being altered

Comment: @DaleK yes they can overlap

Comment: If you have to do it in SQL you could probably write a recursive CTE which walks backwards along your string replacing symbols in the correct order... but tbh its probably not going to be much of an improvement over a cursor. SQL just isn't designed for this sort of thing.

Comment: @DaleK I added another example with overlapping

Comment: Is there a `WHEN 'Dollar' THEN '$'` in there somewhere? Where does `@RepLen` come from? T-SQL isn't really an efficient place for text replacements, especially when cursors are involved. Have you considered writing this as an SQLCLR function?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning This is the main part of the script, RepLen is the length of the RepText, I have never used SQLCLR.
Will it be more effecient with SQLCLR ?

Comment: Probably - because C# is much better suited to string manipulation... but you will only know if you try it. There is still a lot of overhead calling a CLR function 1million times. Thats why I suggested it earlier. And if nothing else, its a damn sight easier to code this sort of thing in C# than T-SQL.

Comment: @asmgx - What version of SQL Server are you using, please?  2022 or something else?  If something else, then which?

Comment: In your first example `This is a test report, will be used for testing` why only 1 `Registered` & `CopyRights` symbol is injected ?

Comment: @DaleK No recursion necessary

Comment: @Squirrel that was a mistake, thanks for spotting it

Comment: for the same `iRepID`, will you have 2 rows with the same `iBegin` or `iEnd` value ?

Answer (score 3):

**You can do this in a single query and without any recursion,** by splitting the string based on your `Injections` table, and then reaggregating along with the injections.

First, transform your table

- The actual injection value such as `©` should be added as a column.
- The rows should be duplicated to split up `iBegin` and `iEnd` into separate rows of a single column `Location`.

Then you can create the following funtion.

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Inject (@value varchar(max), @iRepID int)
RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN

SELECT
  value = STRING_AGG(v.substr + i.Injection, '') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY i.Location)
          + SUBSTRING(@value, MAX(i.Location) + 1, LEN(@value))
FROM (
    SELECT i.*,
      PrevLocation = ISNULL(LAG(i.Location) OVER (ORDER BY i.Location), 0)
    FROM dbo.Injections i
    WHERE i.iRepID = @iRepID
) i
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
      substr = SUBSTRING(@value, i.PrevLocation + 1, i.Location - i.PrevLocation)
) v;
```

We take the table, add a `LAG` to get the previous `Location` in order, and then construct and aggregate substrings of the original value along with the injections, finally adding on the last substring.

You can use directly with a value

```sql
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Inject('This is a test report, will be used for testing', 1001);
```

Or apply it to a table

```sql
SELECT *
FROM dbo.SomeTable st
CROSS APPLY dbo.Inject(st.SomeText, st.iRepID);
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/O1N1Oh_B)

Having said that, I agree that another tool is probably more efficient at string manipulation.

Comment: Depending on final desired outcome, one could add 'AND i.Location <= LEN(@value)' to the WHERE i.iRepID = @iRepID. Example 'Short' becomes 'Sh©or®t©®$$' vs 'Sh©or®t' -- I had gotten stuck on previous position, thanks for introducing me to LAG().